# Assigning a value to a char array (String) in C

Tags: c

I tried to assign a String a value in C, but for me it doesn't work...
This is, what I tried to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char k[25];
k == "Dennis"
printf("My Name is %s", k);
}
```

Sample Output would be: My Name is Dennis

However, I receive the a warning:
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast k == "Dennis";

I tried to find a solution on this website, but could not find one, where it was the same error with assigning a value to a char array (a string) in C

Also tried initializing my char as

```
  char *k[25];
```

still didn't work...

Comment: The code you posted 1) contains a syntax error and 2) doesn't produce the warning you claim it does.

Comment: `==` is comparison, not assignment. `=` is assignment, but you cannot assign to an array.

Comment: look at the library functions strcpy, strncpy

Comment: Perhaps start off getting the code to compile!

Answer (score 6):

1. You are indeed doing a comparison here: `k == "Dennis"`. So the compiler correctly warns you.
2. You probably meant `k = "Dennis";` (fixed the missing semi-colon there). But that won't work either. Because in C arrays are not modifiable lvalues.

So you can either *initialize* the array:

```
char k[25] = "Dennis";
```

or, use `strcpy` to copy:

```
strcpy(k, "Dennis");
```

---

If you actually have no need for an *array*, you can simply use a pointer that points to the string literal. The following is valid:

```
char *k;
k = "Dennis";
printf("My Name is %s", k);
```

Comment: The warning is about different pointer types, but the two types in question are both `char *`.

Comment: thanks a lot! you are my hero! This works perfectly fine.

Comment: @melpomene Perhaps OP posted the "wrong" code in the question. But the crux of the question remains the same.